# Will upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04 restore Unity?

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, unity, gnome, themes

Yesterday, I upgraded my Ubuntu 11.04 tot 11.10. After some trouble I managed to remove Unity and I installed GDM & gnome-shell as a replacement. I configured it a bit: installed some extensions, changed some themes, etc...

My question now is: What will happen if I upgrade my 11.10 to 12.04 (and afterwards to 12.10)? Will Unity get reinstalled and if so: will I lose all my GDM modifications?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: No, it will not reinstall Unity, it will just bring your packages up to date.

Comment: This doens't really answers my question: I quite like gnome-shell so I don't see a reason to step back to the 'old' Ubuntu desktop. I was just wondering what would happen if I upgrade again. If I would use ubuntu-desktop, my question would still stand.